# ELF: Using the section size to calculate an address span

Tags: elf

I was wondering about the size of a section in relation to the address space the section occupies. (I am not assuming dynamic loading or MMUs here)

Does a section size include 0 size symbols if there are any?

For instance say a section size is 100 bytes long and starts at address 0. Naively I would assume that the address space taken by this section would be from 0 to 100.

Assuming however that there are symbols there at address 0, 1, 2 and 3 which have a size of 0 but do have an address associated with them then the actual address space would be 0-103 with 0-3 as being empty?

Are there such symbols?
I am new to the ELF format and not 100% sure how it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering about the size of a section in relation to the address space the section occupies.

A section does not normally occupy any address -- a *segment* does.

`ELF` stands for executable and linkable format, and serves dual purpose: (static) linking and execution.

During the linking phase, the linker operates on *sections*, and assigns them to 0 or more segments (but usually to at most 1 loadable segment). Some sections, such as `.note` or `.comment` usually don't have `SHF_ALLOC` flag set, and do not end up in *any* loadable segment.

Note that sections are not needed after static link, and can be completely stripped out.

During the execution phase, loadable segments are `mmap`ed into the address space. If a section had size 100, had `SHF_ALLOC` flag, and got assigned to some `PT_LOAD` segment, then that section will occupy 100 bytes of the address space.

> (I am not assuming dynamic loading or MMUs here)

Dynamic linking and MMUs are completely orthogonal to what's happening here. By mentioning them, you only muddy the waters.

> For instance say a section size is 100 bytes long and starts at address 0. Naively I would assume that the address space taken by this section would be from 0 to 100.

As stated above, you view of the world is not entirely accurate, and the section is very unlikely to actually occupy the `[0, 100)` address range.

> Assuming however that there are symbols there at address 0, 1, 2 and 3 which have a size of 0 but do have an address associated with them then the actual address space would be 0-103 with 0-3 as being empty?

Symbols are merely *labels* attached to certain addresses. They don't occupy any address space themselves. They can also be completely stripped after (static) link, though usually they are left in to simplify debugging. The presence of these symbols / labels is what allows the debugger to tell you that your program crashes in e.g. `fscanf` called from `foo`, which was called from `main`.

Comment: Therefore from what you are saying is that you cannot determine a segments size from the symbols that exist within the segments address space. Is that correct?

Comment: @Har That's correct: symbols are *not* required to have any size at all. Also, multiple sections can be assigned to a single segment, and these sections may have alignment requirements that would necessitate padding. Adding symbol sizes can give you approximate lower bound (it's possible to have overlapping symbols), but nothing more than that.